# How can i save each line in shared preferences instead of the last line?

Tags: java, android, loops, sharedpreferences

I have this list of countries

> Vatican City
>
> China
>
> Italy
>
> Iran
>
> S. Korea
>
> Spain
>
> Germany
>
> France

i save this list in shared preferences then call it to put it in listview,

the problem is, it got only the last item, so France will saved last and it will be the only one in the listView

How can i solve that? i know with loop, but i'm not good at it

Any help with codes will be appreciated !

Comment: Save it as CSV in one line. Or use the db instead of shared preferences.

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs this will be more hustler, i use shared preference a lot in my app, and i'm used to it

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit the code, so we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel; 
import android.graphics.Color; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView; 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        // By ID get the AutoCompleteTextView 
        // which id is assign in xml file 
        AutoCompleteTextView 
            autoCompleteTextView 
            = (AutoCompleteTextView) 
                findViewById( 
                    R.id.autocompleteTextView); 

        // Create the string array 
        // and store the values. 
        String[] colors 
            = { "Red", "Green", "Black", 
                "Orange", "Blue", "Pink", 
                "Blush", "Brown", "Yellow" }; 

        // Create the object of ArrayAdapter with String 
        // which hold the data as the list item. 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter 
            = new ArrayAdapter<String>( 
                this, 
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, 
                colors); 

        // Give the suggestion after 1 words. 
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1); 

        // Set the adapter for data as a list 
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter); 
        autoCompleteTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 
    } 
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"> 

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:text="Write the color name !"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 

    <AutoCompleteTextView

        android:id="@+id/autocompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

See here for more details:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-auto-complete-textbox-and-how-to-create-it/

If you want to get data which are saved in shared preferences use this code:

```
val j=adapter.count
            var i=0
            while (i<j){
            Log.d("abc",adapter.getItem(i))
            i++}
```

Comment: i think you didn't understand my question, sorry for confusion, colors is the problem, i can put the values coming from a fucntion to that colors varilable, it always shows the last item

Comment: Do you want to put values of shared preferences in a function?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699878/how-can-i-put-a-list-to-array

Comment: Ok, why do you ask two similar questions?