# How can i put a list to array

Tags: android, arrays, sorting, listview, arraylist

How can i put a list of strings, type string

[image]

in

```
  String countryList[] = {a};
```

a is the variable that have the list

so, it will be

```
  String countryList[] = {"heyyesGabon","heyyesGibraltar","heyyesGuinea"}; //and the others
```

this list comes from console.log in javascript

it always save the last item

Comment: just use list.toArray() build function of list

Answer (score 0):

**From List to String array**

```
String [] countryArray = countryList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

**From String array to List**

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-build function `list.toArray(stringArray);`  it will return `String[]`.

```
String countryList[] = new String[list.size()];
countryList = list.toArray(countryList);
```

Hope this will help you.